# Why is the _0 Nat in Shapeless a class instead of an object?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, shapeless, hlist

I'm trying to understand Shapeless, and I came across this:

```
// Base trait for type level natural numbers.
trait Nat {
  type N <: Nat
}

// Encoding of successor.
case class Succ[P <: Nat]() extends Nat {
  type N = Succ[P]
}

// Encoding of zero.
class _0 extends Nat {
  type N = _0
}
```

`_0` is a special and unique case, like `Nil` for a `List`. `_0` has no predecessor.  Why isn't it an object/case object (which is a singleton)?  `HList`s seem to do this:

```
// `HList` ADT base trait.
sealed trait HList

// Non-empty `HList` element type.
final case class ::[+H, +T <: HList](head : H, tail : T) extends HList {
  override def toString = head+" :: "+tail.toString
}

// Empty `HList` element type.
sealed trait HNil extends HList {
  def ::[H](h : H) = shapeless.::(h, this)
  override def toString = "HNil"
}

// Empty `HList` value.
case object HNil extends HNil
```

Answer (score 0):

(Just guessing, I don't know the original reason.)

Maybe so that a *type* `_0` is available (to pass it explicitly like in `def fun[N <: Nat] = ???; fun[_0]`, or more simply to define implicits about this type).

If `_0` would have been a singleton, only type `_0.type` would have been available.

And same thing for `HNil` ?

Comment: It's not a good reason not to make it a singleton type. To have convenience that you're talking about, you can just write `case object _0 Extends Nat` and `type _0 = _0.type`